# How does one read the data value from a Function outside FunctionCallbackInfo?

Tags: v8

When I create a function like this:

```
v8::Function::New(<Isolate>, <C_Function>, <Data_Value>);
```

The `Data_Value` that I supply is useful for many things and I can access that when the function is called, with something like `FunctionCallbackInfo->GetData()`.

But I have found no way to get back this `data` in a different scenario. Let's say I store that Function in a Persistent object, and then I would like to read which `data` is currently bound to it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's exposed via the API.

But there's an alternative:

1. manually construct a `v8::FunctionTemplate`
2. set its `->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount(num_fields)`
3. get the `v8::Function` from the template with `template->GetFunction(context)`,
4. now you should have `function->InternalFieldCount() == num_fields`
5. you can use `function->SetInternalField(index, value)` and `function->GetInternalField(index)` to store any data you want.

For complete examples, search for "SetInternalFieldCount" in V8's [test-api.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/master/test/cctest/test-api.cc).